# C#: преобразование координат из XPS для PDF

Tags: c#, изображения, pdf, преобразование, координаты

Как преобразовать координаты (**OriginX** и **OriginY**), извлеченные из ***.xps\Documents\1\Pages\1.fpage** в систему координат для **PDF**?

На данный момент достал координаты (**OriginX** и **OriginY**) нужной мне строки из **XPS**., конвертировал файл в **PDF** и разместил картинку по найденным координатам.

Проблема в том, что картинка разместилась даже не рядом с той строкой (координаты которой нашел), которую хотел закрыть картинкой.